# how to return unique product IDs in five table/view query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a complex query that shown in the below picture
[image]

```
SELECT        dbo.product.id, dbo.product.productType, dbo.View_product_category.catId, dbo.product_barcodes.id AS barcodeId, dbo.product_barcodes.barcode, dbo.product_price.type AS priceType, dbo.product_price.priceBuy, 
                         dbo.product_price.priceJoz, dbo.product_price.priceKol, dbo.product_price.pricePacket, dbo.product.kolNumber, dbo.product.count, dbo.product.isDeleted, dbo.product.brand, dbo.product.measurementUnit, 
                         dbo.View_product_category.name AS catName, dbo.product_translations.name AS productName, dbo.product.isAlarmForMinCount, dbo.product.minCountForAlarm, dbo.product.sellIfNoExists
FROM            dbo.product_translations RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.product ON dbo.product_translations.product_id = dbo.product.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.View_product_category ON dbo.product.id = dbo.View_product_category.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.product_barcodes ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_barcodes.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.product_price ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_price.product_id
WHERE        (dbo.product_barcodes.id IN
                             (SELECT        MAX(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.product_barcodes AS product_barcodes_1
                               GROUP BY product_id)) AND (dbo.product_translations.isdefault = 1) AND (dbo.product_price.type = 2)
```

I delete duplicate barcodes by this WHERE

```
    WHERE        (dbo.product_barcodes.id IN
                             (SELECT        MAX(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.product_barcodes AS product_barcodes_1
                               GROUP BY product_id))
```

how to delete duplicate Id??
I want to return 1 record for the product with id 31 in the below picture:
[image]

sorry for my bad English.

Comment: update your question ad  add  code as text not as image ..

Comment: How do you mean duplicate catId, when you have two distinct values: 1 and 2???

Comment: it's edited excuse me

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are very different products. Don't use both tags unless you want to ask something for *both* databases. This looks like SQL Server

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It would help if you could post sample data and expected results - in the screen shot you show, it appears that id 31 has two matching records in View_product_category, with different cat_id values - which one do you want to discard?

Comment: As for how to find and remove duplicates, you'll find a lot of duplicate questions that show how to use `ROW_NUMBER OVER()` to rank rows by the columns you use to detect duplicates, then delete those whose row number is >1. This works in all supported SQL Server versions. It also works in MySQL 8.0. There's no need for the `SELECT MAX() ....` subquery. Using ranking is a lot faster too, as those subqueries have to run before the outer query can be evaluated, resulting in two table scans instead of one

Comment: BTW The two rows with ID 31 aren't duplicate. The two rows have a different `catId` values. Post the table schemas, test data and desired output so people can understand what you mean, what you expect. It could be that the rest of the query is wrong

Comment: Looks like Powerbuilder to me, not C#.

Comment: there is a many to many relation between product and category tables And between product and barcode tables and between product and price tables, I want to fetch my products with maximum price and category and barcode

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes , Arent duplicate but I want return one 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your WHERE phrase, you are using GROUP BY and you can repeat this for View_product_category
I guess below code is your answer

```
 (dbo.View_product_category.proCatId IN
                         (SELECT        MIN(proCatId) AS expr
                           FROM            dbo.View_product_category AS View_product_category_1
                           GROUP BY product_id))
```

and complete query is

```
    SELECT        dbo.product.id, dbo.product.productType, dbo.View_product_category.catId, dbo.product_barcodes.id AS barcodeId, dbo.product_barcodes.barcode, dbo.product_price.type AS priceType, dbo.product_price.priceBuy, 
                         dbo.product_price.priceJoz, dbo.product_price.priceKol, dbo.product_price.pricePacket, dbo.product.kolNumber, dbo.product.count, dbo.product.isDeleted, dbo.product.brand, dbo.product.measurementUnit, 
                         dbo.View_product_category.name AS catName, dbo.product_translations.name AS productName, dbo.product.isAlarmForMinCount, dbo.product.minCountForAlarm, dbo.product.sellIfNoExists
FROM            dbo.product_translations RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.product ON dbo.product_translations.product_id = dbo.product.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.View_product_category ON dbo.product.id = dbo.View_product_category.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.product_barcodes ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_barcodes.product_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.product_price ON dbo.product.id = dbo.product_price.product_id
WHERE        (dbo.View_product_category.proCatId IN
                             (SELECT        MIN(proCatId) AS expr
                               FROM            dbo.View_product_category AS View_product_category_1
                               GROUP BY product_id)) AND (dbo.product_translations.isdefault = 1) AND (dbo.product_price.type = 2) AND (dbo.product_barcodes.id IN
                             (SELECT        MAX(id) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.product_barcodes AS product_barcodes_1
                               GROUP BY product_id))
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method in SQL Server is:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES . . .
FROM . . .
. . .
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product.id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
```

This is not the most efficient method, but it should have reasonable performance.

Notes:

- Learn to use table aliases!  Using the full table name is hard to write and even harder to read.
- The table alases should be abbreviations -- hint:  `tr` for `product_translations`.
- I have written lots and lots of SQL and have never had to mix `LEFT` and `RIGHT JOIN`s.  Start with the table where you want to keep all the rows and then just use `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: my query is built with sql server, right join and left join is depended on the base table, thanks for your reply

Comment: @david2020 the query is written using the designer, not SQL Server. It's no different than queries written by hand - that `MAX()` had to be written by hand in fact. In general, the designer isn't perfect and is usually only used as a quick way to get started. In any case, the designer *can* work with table aliases, although it's usually quicker to just edit the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos even worse is that the designer is creating queries with deprecated syntax. 3 & 4 part naming in the list of columns has been deprecated for awhile now. Seems that if MS can't adhere to this then there is little to now chance it will actually be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there may be a language problem - it sounds as if you have a query and it's returning more rows than you want. I don't think you want to `delete` anything.

The reason you are seeing two instances of product ID 31 is that there are two matching records in `View_product_category` with different `catIDs` (1 and 2). Without knowing more about the data, it's hard to be certain how to deal with that; the query below limits them to records with CatId 1.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.productType,
  vpc.catId,
  pb.id AS barcodeId,
  pb.barcode,
  pp.type AS priceType,
  pp.priceBuy,
  pp.priceJoz,
  pp.priceKol,
  pp.pricePacket,
  p.kolNumber,
  p.count,
  p.isDeleted,
  p.brand,
  p.measurementUnit,
  vpc.name AS catName,
  pt.name AS productName,
  p.isAlarmForMinCount,
  p.minCountForAlarm,
  p.sellIfNoExists
FROM dbo.product_translations pt
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.product p ON pt.product_id = p.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.View_product_category vpc ON p.id = vpc.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.product_barcodes pb ON p.id = pb.product_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.product_price pp ON p.id = pp.product_id
WHERE
  (
    pb.id IN (
      SELECT
        MAX(id) AS Expr1
      FROM dbo.product_barcodes AS product_barcodes_1
      GROUP BY
        product_id
    )
  )
  AND pt.isdefault = 1
  AND pp.type = 2)
  AND vpc.catId = 1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but catId is variable and 'AND vpc.catId = 1' is'nt my answer

Comment: Which one do you want to include - a random one, the highest, lowest?